# libGDX html build always fails: compileGwtException

Tags: java, gradle, gwt, libgdx

I'm trying to build a [libGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) application and targeting HTML as distribution goal.

The setup using the JAR setup app ran successfully. I have ticked only HTML as output (for the sake of this question) and added no extensions. The files are all left as generated.

But whenever I try to build it, it fails:

```
[tobias@LapTobTob test]$ ./gradlew html:dist
:html:clean
:html:addSource
:core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:core:processResources NO-SOURCE
:core:classes UP-TO-DATE
:core:jar UP-TO-DATE
:html:compileJavawarning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
1 warning

:html:processResources NO-SOURCE
:html:compileGwtException in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.util.regexfilter.RegexFilter: method <init>()V not found
        at com.google.gwt.util.regexfilter.WhitelistRegexFilter.<init>(WhitelistRegexFilter.java:21)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JJSOptionsImpl.<init>(JJSOptionsImpl.java:54)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.PrecompileTaskOptionsImpl.<init>(PrecompileTaskOptionsImpl.java:39)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.CompilerOptionsImpl.<init>(CompilerOptionsImpl.java:30)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:108)
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':html:compileGwt'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
6 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 2 up-to-date
```

System:

- OS: Archlinux \w kernel 5.1.15
- JAVA: java-8-openjdk
- libGDX: 1.9.9

Comment: btw, I do have an ouptut with the `--debug` option, but it is ~600K in size; pastebin.com doesn't accept it. Is there another way to publish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if in your html project's build.gradle file GWT version is set to 2.8.0. 1.9.9 relies in 2.8.0 and the setup tool might have created it with 2.8.2 because that's what 1.9.10-SNAPSHOT uses.

Comment: It was indeed set to 2.8.2. I changed manually it to 2.8.0 and it compiled without errors. Thanks!

Comment: But what should be the webapp template? I was expecting the red background with the Badlogic logo, but I was faced with a big gray kinda reload button, which doesn't do anything. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: The gray button is normal, but you should face a short time of the preload logo and then the same that you have on other builds (the badlogic logo)

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. I was running it from the wrong directory.

Answer (score 1):

You have some mixture of versions of GWT jars - [the `RegexFilter` class was added in GWT 2.8.1](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_8_1), so some part of your build relies on 2.8.1+, but apparently you still have some jars from before 2.8.1 being brought in to your build.

Additionally, as you are running on Java 9, you must use GWT 2.8.2, as [support to run on Java 9 was only added in 2.8.2](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_8_2).

Ensure that only GWT 2.8.2 is present when the GWT build runs (check both your project's dependencies and what the gwt compile tasks brings in), and no earlier versions.

Comment: I do use Java 8, but I will take a look into the versions of GWT